# How to fully remove calabash-ios / robotframework

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, robotframework, calabash

I'm having some difficulty properly removing some software that I installed on OS X Mavericks; Xcode 5.1.  I installed robotframework and calabash-ios for some automation research; but have decided its not for me.  The commands I initially ran were:

sudo easy_install robotframework

sudo easy_install pip

pip install --upgrade robotframework-ioslibrary

gem install calabash-cucumber

Then duplicated one of my Xcode projects and ran these commands in the project folder:

calabash-ios setup

calabash-ios gen

It seemed logical that I'd just run; gem uninstall calabash-cucumber, and pip uninstall robotframework-ioslibrary

However my problem is that even after running these uninstall commands; that I now have this inspector dropdown show in the top right of my simulator, even for projects that I didn't setup calabash for; see image below (this is what I want to get rid of when I mean "fully remove"):

[image: iOS simulator showing calabash / robotframework inspector]
Many thanks for any help or suggestions.
Reece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That frame you are seeing is the AXInspector.

Calabash iOS requires that Accessibility be enabled to work.  I am not sure what moved the AXInspector to the corner of the Simulator.

The easiest way to remove the AXInspect is to use the iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings menu item.

**WARNING** Resetting content and Settings will remove any installed apps and change all settings back to the default.

Alternatively, you can open the Settings.app on the simulator and disable Accessibility.

NB. The 0.9.169 release of Calabash iOS gem will enable accessibility automatically and hide the AXInspector.